# Error 503 when logging into Joomla backend?

Tags: joomla

I receive a constant 503 (Service unavailable) error recently when trying to log into my Joomla account as an administrator.

Joomla version: 4.6.5
PHP version 5.6

No changes were made to my website during the last weeks.
My host is Strato in Germany.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the problem was solved.

An analysis of the situation and a Google research revealed that in some cases a login was blocked when the request came from countries outside the host country, Germany. This seems to be only true for login to backend requests, not the normal website traffic. Until recently, the blocking was not in effect from Switzerland, now it obviously was.

Solution: I now use a VPN when I want to log into the Joomla backend from Switzerland.